# Video section design not aligned

Tags: html, css

I am working to make video section look like something similar to below design
[image]

i am facing two design breaks in the right side

thumbnail doesn't fill the "vp-hqdefault-w" it shows part of image and rest of it is hidden.

second i am not able to align video title next to thumbnail as show in image

```
<div class="container">


 <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6">
      <div class="active-iframe-wrapper video-embed-container">
          <iframe id='activeIFrame' class='active-iframe' width='100%' height='324' src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/SCRUg5s389Q?showinfo=0&modestbranding=1" ></iframe>
       </div>

      <p>Title of the video</p>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6">

       <a class="" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/SCRUg5s389Q?showinfo=0&modestbranding=1">
      <div class="vp-video-img-w vp-hqdefault-w">
        <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/SCRUg5s389Q/hqdefault.jpg" title="">                                  
      </div>
        <div class="vp-video-details">
          <h3 class="video-title">Mr. Bean is back on the road One</h3>
        </div>
      </a>


      <a class="" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/QThP5kDUJJ0?showinfo=0&modestbranding=1">
      <div class="vp-video-img-w vp-hqdefault-w">
        <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/QThP5kDUJJ0/hqdefault.jpg" title="">                                  
      </div>
        <div class="vp-video-details">
          <h3 class="video-title">Mr. Bean is back on the road Two</h3>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a class="" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xIOP1PLjUTs?showinfo=0&modestbranding=1">
      <div class="vp-video-img-w vp-hqdefault-w">
        <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/xIOP1PLjUTs/hqdefault.jpg" title="">                                  
      </div>
        <div class="vp-video-details">
          <h3 class="video-title">Mr. Bean is back on the road Three</h3>
        </div>
      </a>

    </div>

  </div>
```

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/geEmxg?editors=1100)

I am trying to make it responsive to it doesnt break

Answer (score 1):

You are having this issue because you didn't add `float:left` property to the video thumnail div. Try this code.

```
.vp-video-img-w {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 30%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```css
.header {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.video-embed-container {
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 56.25%;
 height: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 max-width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.active-iframe-wrapper {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.video-embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.video-item-w{
  background-color:#ccc;
}

.vp-hqdefault-w {
 max-height: 80px;
 max-width: 120px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
   width:30%;
}
.vp-video-img-w {
 position: relative;
 width: 30%;
 overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}
.vp-video-details{
  width:70%;
  float:left;
}
.vp-video-img-w img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.video-thumbnail:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear:both;
}

.footer {
  border-top: 1px solid #444;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #999
}

.p {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 120px;
}

.p a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  

 <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6">
      <div class="active-iframe-wrapper video-embed-container">
          <iframe id='activeIFrame' class='active-iframe' width='100%' height='324' src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/SCRUg5s389Q?showinfo=0&modestbranding=1" ></iframe>
       </div>
      
      <p>Title of the video</p>
    </div>
   
   
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6">
     
       <a class="video-thumbnail" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/SCRUg5s389Q?showinfo=0&modestbranding=1">
      <div class="vp-video-img-w vp-hqdefault-w">
        <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/SCRUg5s389Q/hqdefault.jpg" title="">                                  
      </div>
        <div class="vp-video-details">
          <h3 class="video-title">Mr. Bean is back on the road One</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    
      
      <a class="video-thumbnail" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/QThP5kDUJJ0?showinfo=0&modestbranding=1">
      <div class="vp-video-img-w vp-hqdefault-w">
        <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/QThP5kDUJJ0/hqdefault.jpg" title="">                                  
      </div>
        <div class="vp-video-details">
          <h3 class="video-title">Mr. Bean is back on the road Two</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
      
      <a class="video-thumbnail" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xIOP1PLjUTs?showinfo=0&modestbranding=1">
      <div class="vp-video-img-w vp-hqdefault-w">
        <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/xIOP1PLjUTs/hqdefault.jpg" title="">                                  
      </div>
        <div class="vp-video-details">
          <h3 class="video-title">Mr. Bean is back on the road Three</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
       
    </div>
   
  </div>
```

Comment: I am not able to run the code, not sure it is just me

Comment: It breaks when i on large screen

Comment: On which screen size?

Comment: I mean when you resize the codepen window. anyway i made more changes to it looks better but still breaks

Comment: Sorry but i am not getting what is broken?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
.vp-video-img-w {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

to

```
.vp-video-img-w {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}
```